# Like a Page in Facebook TAB and Give the Link

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am creating a Facebook Tab Application. People create their profile and each profile has a like button.  The person who gets the most likes wins.

The problem we are facing now is how to give the URL to a user, so that the user can share the url (so that they can get more likes).  Suppose I give the url `fb.com/appname/id=12`? Should I be able to get the details of user with id `12` in my Facebook Tab Application?

with the graph API?

Answer (score 3):

As a solution for this you can use app_data parameter. You can pass additional parameters to a FB tab using app_data parameter in your url like this
https://www.facebook.com/pages/FB-App-Test13191195702111?sk=app_234567890&app_data=MY_CUSTOM_DATA

```
<?php
$data = array();
$signed_request = '';
$app_data = '';
if(isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
    $signed_request = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
    $secret = YOUR_APP_SECRET
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
    $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

    if(isset($data['app_data'])) {
        $app_data = $data['app_data'];
    }
}
```

Use above php code to read your custom data in url to $app_data

$app_data will be equals to "MY_CUSTOM_DATA".